# while i am trying to access the files from postman and find patterns accordingly i am not getting the file from the pdf_file field

Tags: django, pdfplumber

can anyone tell me how to get the file and extract data from it from postman

```
class ReadPDFView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
      
        data = request.data.get('pdf_file')  
        # Assuming you want to extract text from the first page
        with pdfplumber.open(data) as pdfs :
         first_page_text=pdfs.pages[0]
         first_page_text= extract_text(pdfs)
         print(first_page_text)
        
        return Response(first_page_text)
```

I tried this to get the result